# React - Return components dynamically through function arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have SPA where I render different sections (Components). I like to be able to toggle 2 different components and render one based on a cookie. I was thinking of creating a function that accepts the names of the 2 components I'd want to toggle.

General approach to this

```
renderSection(componentA, componentB, cookie) {
        const ComponentA = upperFirst(componentA);
        const ComponentB = upperFirst(componentB);

        return cookie ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />;
}
```

I would call the function: `renderSection('BottomSection', 'FlexSection', 'cookie')`

However, I receive the following warning:
`Warning: <BottomSection /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.`

I've seen examples where you can assign components to keys within an object and then return the component based on the input you provide. But since I can have many sections to render, I think this object will become confusing to maintain as I'd have to add/remove keys as I update the component.

```
components = {
        foo: FooComponent,
        bar: BarComponent
    };
return components["foo"]
```

Since I'm already requiring each component, is there a way to return a component without having to create an object and define each component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass component name as string, you can pass the component itself to the function as it's just a javascript object

You can do the following

```
renderSection(ComponentA, ComponentB, cookie) {
     return cookie ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />;
}
```

then

```
renderSection(BottomSection, FlexSection, 'cookie')
```

Notice how `renderSection` function accept the component argument name with first letter Capitalized.